# Append an option and make it as a selected value in the select2 directive in vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2, vue-directives

I've created a select2 directive in vue 2 like this:

```js
// Select2 directive file

import Vue from "vue";

function updateFunction (el, binding) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        Vue.nextTick(function () {
            let options = binding.value || {};
            $(el).select2(Object.assign({}, {
            }, options))
            .on("select2:select select2:unselect", (e) => {
                el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { target: e.target }));
            })
            .on('change', function(e) {
                if (e.detail === "vue-directive") {
                  return; // prevent stack overflow (i.e. listening to the event we threw ourselves)
                }
                // throw regular change (non jQuery) event, so vue reacts
                el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change", {
                  detail: "vue-directive"
                }));
                return false;
              });
        });
    }, 500);
}

// Initialize the directive.
export const select = {
    inserted: updateFunction,
    componentUpdated: updateFunction,
    params: ["placeholder"]
};

Vue.directive("select2", select);
```

and I use the select2 in vue files like this:

```js
import { select } from "./directives/select2";

new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      user_id: "",
      select_options: {
        ajax: {
            url: "/myAPI",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization:
                  "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("api_token")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            processResults: function(data) {
              // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
              var json = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                  var config = {
                      id: "",
                      text: ""
                  };
                  config.id = data.data[i].id;
                  config.text = data.data[i].name;
                  json.push(config);
              }
              return {
                  results: json
              };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  directives: {
      select
  }
})
```

```html
<select v-select="select_options" v-model="user_id"></select>
```

The issue is I need to update the select2 input when mounted() calls
I don't have a clue how should I handle this issue
If anyone knows how can I do that I would appreciate that.
I think this would be very great if you know I give the information from an API and the value of options will be the id of each option.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem in this way:

```js
import { select } from "./directives/select2";

new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      user_id: "",
      select_options: {
        name: "this is a test",
        id: "1",
        ajax: {
            url: "/myAPI",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization:
                  "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("api_token")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            processResults: function(data) {
              // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
              var json = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                  var config = {
                      id: "",
                      text: ""
                  };
                  config.id = data.data[i].id;
                  config.text = data.data[i].name;
                  json.push(config);
              }
              return {
                  results: json
              };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  directives: {
      select
  }
})
```

and I changed the directive as this

```js
function updateFunction (el, binding) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        Vue.nextTick(function () {
            if (binding.value.name && binding.value.id) {
                var newOption = new Option(
                    binding.value.name,
                    binding.value.id,
                    false,
                    false
                );
                $(el)
                    .append(newOption)
                    .trigger("change");
            }
            let options = binding.value || {};
            $(el).select2(Object.assign({}, {
            }, options))
            .on("select2:select select2:unselect", (e) => {
                el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { target: e.target }));
            })
            .on('change', function(e) {
                if (e.detail === "vue-directive") {
                  return; // prevent stack overflow (i.e. listening to the event we threw ourselves)
                }
                // throw regular change (non jQuery) event, so vue reacts
                el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change", {
                  detail: "vue-directive"
                }));
                return false;
              });
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

It will investigate if there was a name and id in the value of binding it will set it to the initiate option.